# List all environment id in openai gym

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

How to list all **currently registered** environment IDs (as they are used for creating environments) in openai gym?

A bit context: there are many plugins installed which have customary ids such as atari, super mario, doom etc.

Not to be confused with game names for atari-py.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `envs.registry.all()`:

```
from gym import envs
print(envs.registry.all())
```

Out:

> dict_values([EnvSpec(Copy-v0), EnvSpec(RepeatCopy-v0), EnvSpec(ReversedAddition-v0), EnvSpec(ReversedAddition3-v0), EnvSpec(DuplicatedInput-v0), EnvSpec(Reverse-v0), EnvSpec(CartPole-v0), ...])

This returns a large collection of `EnvSpec` objects, not specifically of the IDs as you asked. You can get those like this:

```
from gym import envs
all_envs = envs.registry.all()
env_ids = [env_spec.id for env_spec in all_envs]
print(sorted(env_ids))
```

Out:

> ['Acrobot-v1', 'Ant-v2', 'Ant-v3', 'BipedalWalker-v3', 'BipedalWalkerHardcore-v3', 'Blackjack-v1', 'CarRacing-v0', 'CartPole-v0', 'CartPole-v1', ...]

Comment: @MikeWoodcock Probably not, since those seem to be in a separate repository. The page you linked to does mention that all environments can be listed using `retro.data.list_games()`, so... that's probably what you'll want to do.

Comment: To print each IDs on seperated line, just do: `import gym ; print(*sorted([env_spec.id for env_spec in gym.envs.registry.all()]), sep="\n")`

Comment: @milembar or just use `pprint(envs.registry.keys())`

Comment: If you upgrade to `gymnasium`, you can also `gymnasium.pprint_registry()`

Answer (score 5):

as of 2022 use this method

```py
from gym import envs
envs.registry.keys()
```

That will give you something like this

```py
dict_keys(['CartPole-v0', 'CartPole-v1', 'MountainCar-v0', 'MountainCarContinuous-v0', 'Pendulum-v1', 'Acrobot-v1', 'LunarLander-v2', 'LunarLanderContinuous-v2', 'BipedalWalker-v3', 'BipedalWalkerHardcore-v3', 'CarRacing-v2', 'Blackjack-v1', 'FrozenLake-v1', 'FrozenLake8x8-v1', 'CliffWalking-v0', 'Taxi-v3', 'Reacher-v2', 'Reacher-v4', 'Pusher-v2', 'Pusher-v4', 'InvertedPendulum-v2', 'InvertedPendulum-v4', 'InvertedDoublePendulum-v2', 'InvertedDoublePendulum-v4', 'HalfCheetah-v2', 'HalfCheetah-v3', 'HalfCheetah-v4', 'Hopper-v2', 'Hopper-v3', 'Hopper-v4', 'Swimmer-v2', 'Swimmer-v3', 'Swimmer-v4', 'Walker2d-v2', 'Walker2d-v3', 'Walker2d-v4', 'Ant-v2', 'Ant-v3', 'Ant-v4', 'Humanoid-v2', 'Humanoid-v3', 'Humanoid-v4', 'HumanoidStandup-v2', 'HumanoidStandup-v4'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code for listing all environments in gym:

```
import gym
for i in gym.envs.registry.all():
  print(i.id)
```

Comment: How is this answer different than accepted one ?